# placeins: options section and below

Tags: sectioning, floats, placeins

I am using the package `placeins` with the options `section` and `below` so the floats will appear in their sections below their section if on the same page; however, the float is appearing above its section which is on the same page.
My document class is `article`.

[image]

So why aren't the floats obeying the options I have in place?

Comment: Are you using `[htbp]`? Add only `\begin{figure}[b]`

Comment: Why? Do you have two columns?

Comment: @percusse no it is just habit but it should operate the same as using just `figure`, correct?

Comment: I give the floor to the master http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/3235

Comment: @percusse I changed `figure*` to `figure` but the outcome is the same.

Comment: Do you have your figure code before the section command? Move it down a little if that is the case

Comment: @percusse the figure code is in the appropriate section.

Comment: Well then we hit the usual MWE discussion.

Comment: @percusse I tried to create MWE but it doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Load the package with the verbose option: `\usepackage[section,below,verbose]{placeins}`; the `.log` file will show you what happened to floats; look for information about the problematic one.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina there isn't anything special in the `.log` file.  All it says is: `Package placeins Info: Float barrier, from input line 560, processed on page 8,
 lands on page 8.`

Comment: If the MWE doesn't do what you want, then the problem is in some other part of the document. You should always be able to make a MWE just start with the document that shows the problem and remove everything while still showing the problem.

Comment: You probably want to use the standard `flafter` package to stop the float moving backwards (`placeins` is mainly about stopping floats moving to far forwards) but without an example, it is hard to be sure.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can't find anything on ctan in regards to `flafter` package.

Comment: `flafter` is part of the base latex distribution, same as say `article` class.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how do I access documentation on it?

Comment: @dustin interesting question it is part of the latex base source, so documented in source2e, but that's not the most gentle read, there are no commands just `\usepackage{flafter}` and some examples here http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=flafter

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried using `flafter` with `placeins` and nothing changed.  I tried just using `flafter` and the floats were all before they were defined.

Comment: @dustin you've been on the site long enough to know the mantra: questions without a working example are not really answerable

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried creating one by using the `lipsum` package to position the figures near the bottom of a page and then issuing a new `\section` but I couldn't re-create the problem.  It is not that I didn't try.  This just isn't easy for me to recreate.  I wanted the figures and new section near a page break since that is where the issue cropped up but the MWE isn't doing it.

Comment: rather than lipsum which is hard to control the text length just use `sometext\\[26\baselineskip]moretext\par` to make something that takes the space of a 28line paragraph, then you can easily mess with the numbers to make things come near a page break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With or without `placeins` you can prevent a float floating "backwards" to the top of the page with its definition by using

```
\usepackage{flafter}
```

which is part of the base latex distribution.