# Control figures grouped inside a section when there are a lot of them

Tags: floats, sectioning, article

I am working in my homework where there are a lot of figures.

I have a visual problem with figures which they must only placed inside a specific section, but they are shown in the next section. This is because I have a little text, and `LaTeX` tries to arrange my paragraphs and text for the best.

Is there any solution for that? I have tried with `\hspace` and `\newpage`, but doesn't work.
I am working with `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}`, maybe I have to use another kind of document for my homework.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried `\FloatBarrier` from the [`placeins`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/placeins?lang=en) package?

Comment: @jon Thanks it works. I followed Gonzalo Medina suggestion: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132163/placeins-options-section-and-below#comment298366_132163